# Salvar arquivos csv no Python depois de fazer alterações?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo algumas alterações em vários arquivos csv ao mesmo tempo, e gostaria de saber como que faço para salvar a saída em um único arquivo.

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('Downloads/Dados_PNBoia/teste/*.csv')
dataset.loc[(dataset[' yyyy']==2018) & (dataset[' temp']!=-99999)]
dataset['size'] = (dataset[' temp']+273.15) #também não consegui fazer esse acréscimo na coluna, após filtra-la
```

O que pode ser feito para faltar esse arquivo? P.S.: Tentei somar uma quantidade a coluna ' temp' após filtrar, mas não sai com o valor novo.
Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Você pode concatenar seus dataframe de modo a ter um único dataframe. Por exemplo:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('arq01.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('arq02.csv')

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Daí tu faz os seus filtros e depois salva o seu dataframe em um único arquivo, desta forma:

```
df3.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Ele junta todos os dados, mas não os que eu queria filtrar. Vem todos os dados originais.

Comment: Consegui, só modifiquei uma parte e ele salvou direitinho. Obrigada